# Db2 Warehouse MDC foreign key relations

Tags: sql, db2, foreign-keys, relational-database, ibm-cloud

I have a Db2 database with two tables, TABLE_A and TABLE_B.

This is how I create TABLE_A (ORGANIZED BY DIMENSIONS):

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_A (
COL1 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
COL2 INT NOT NULL,
COL3 INT NOT NULL)
ORGANIZE BY DIMENSIONS (COL1, COL2);
```

This is how I create TABLE_B (ORGANIZED BY ROW):

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_B (
COL1 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
COL2 INT NOT NULL,
COL3 INT NOT NULL)
ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

I want to create a parent-child relation between the tables with COL1 as a primary key in TABLE_A and as a foreign key in TABLE_B.

The problem is that I can't make COL1 in the MDC (Multidimensional clustering) table, TABLE_A, a primary key.

With the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE "PARTITIONING_TEST"."TABLE_A" ADD CONSTRAINT "TABLE_A_PK" PRIMARY KEY
("COL1") ENFORCED;
```

I get the error:

```
The primary key or a unique key identified by "TABLE_A_PK" is a subset of the columns in the ORGANIZE BY clause.. SQLCODE=-20188, SQLSTATE=429BE, DRIVER=4.22.36
```

And as I can not make COL1 a primary key in TABLE_A I can not make it a foreign key in TABLE_B.

How can I create this relation?

Answer (score 0):

You really would not want to MDC on your primary key. Luckily DB2 stops you from doing that, as the error message explains

```
All the columns in a primary or unique key are included in the table's
ORGANIZE BY clause. This is not allowed, since each block of pages in
the table would contain just one row, wasting all the rest of the space
in the block.
```

You would typically MDC on columns such as e.g.  SALES_DATE or (if you don't have that many sales) SALES_YEAR_MONTH  and maybe SALES_REGION etc. I.e. *low cardanility* columns, and certainly not your Primary Key. The manual explains MDC tables quite well I think. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.partition.doc/doc/c0022241.html